# How can I convert an Excel cell containing escaped unicode char?

Tags: excel-formula

I have cells containing text along with escaped unicode char, like : sue\u00f1os

I would like using a formula to decode the unicode char and obtain : sueños

I looked at the UNICODE or UNICHAR functions, but they are not matching what I require.

Comment: Using excel formulas you could try to extract unicode part, convert to intigers and pass to `UNICHAR` function to get the correct character and then substitute it back to get correct string. Doable but seems like a lot of hassle. I personally would suggest using vba or python for this. Or if you don't have to automate this just use "Find and replace" option.

Answer (score 0):

With a your example in cell A1, then in legacy Excel

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("\u",A1)-1)&UNICHAR(HEX2DEC(MID(A1,FIND("\u",A1)+2,4)))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("\u",A1)-5)
```

or, in dynamic-array Excel,

```
=LET(pos,FIND("\u",A1),LEFT(A1,pos-1)&UNICHAR(HEX2DEC(MID(A1,pos+2,4)))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-pos-5))
```

but I have to agree about using *Find & Replace*, especially if you only have a few distinct UNICODE characters to replace - unlike with VBA, in being able to iterate through the whole workbook, this is one UI feature that is more efficient than when effected through code.